# How to inject same dbcontext instance between Service and Repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

hi I am working on a project and currently i am building data layer with entity framework

**Dbcontext**

```
public interface IDatabaseContext : IDisposable 
    {        
        IDbSet<TestEntity> TestEntitys { get; }
        int SaveChanges();
    }



public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
    {
        static DatabaseContext()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        }

        public DatabaseContext(string connectionString) :
            base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {          

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestEntityConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }                  

        public IDbSet<TestEntity> TestEntitys
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {           

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

**unit of work:**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{   
    int Commit();
    IDatabaseContext Context { get; }
}

  public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{

    private  IDatabaseContext _dbContext;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseContext mydbContext)
    {    
         //var builder=DataBaseConnectionStringBuilder();
         //var factory = new DataBaseConnectionFactory(builder);      

        _dbContext = mydbContext;

    }

    public int Commit()
    {

        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IDatabaseContext Context
    {
        get { return _dbContext; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {     
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_dbContext != null)
                {
                    _dbContext.Dispose();
                    _dbContext = null;
                }
            }
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class Baseservice()
{
    protacted IUnitOfWork unitofwork;
    public BaseService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        unitofwork= uow;
    }
}
public class TestEntityservice() : BaseService
{
    private ITestEntityReopsitory _testEntityReopsitory;
    public TestEntityservice(IUnitOfWork uow,ITestEntityReopsitory testEntityReopsitory):base(uow)
    {
        _testEntityReopsitory=testEntityReopsitory;
    }
    public int AddNewData(somedto dto){

        var result=_testEntityReopsitory.AddTEst(dto);
        return  unitofwork.Commit();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
 public BaseRepository(IDatabaseContext context)
        {
            _dbContext = context;            
        }
public class TestEntityReopsitory() : BaseRepository, ITestEntityReopsitory
{

    public TestEntityReopsitory(IDatabaseContext context) :base(context) {        
    }
    public int AddTEst(somedto dto){
        var entity = new TestEntity()
        {
            a= dto.a,
            b= dto.b
        }
        context.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

My concern is as i am injecting  My database context(DatabaseContext) in repository so when the repository will resolve it will have a **separate instance** **of dbcontext in repository then service**.  So that means i am adding an entity to a separate context and saving using a different context.

How can i make sure that i am using the same instance in repository and service and still keep my same implementation.

Comment: You could also try `NInject` or any other dependency injector to archive the same idea with the factory classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UnitOfWork class, instead of creating a factory and then using it to create an IDatabaseContext object, use constructor injection to injection a DatabaseContext. Like this:

```
public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseContext db_context)
{    
    _dbContext = db_context;
}
```

Also do the same thing for Baseservice (and thus TestEntityservice), they should be injected with IUnitOfWork in their constructor, they should not create the UnitOfWork themselves. This is what dependency injection is all about.

After making sure you use constructor injection, you can now compose the whole object graph in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). When you do that, make sure that you use the same DatabaseContext instance for both your UnitOfWork and your service. [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) is a very good way to do such composition.

Here is how to do this with Pure DI:

```
    var connection_string = "some connection string";

    using (IDatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(connection_string))
    {
        IUnitOfWork unit_of_work = new UnitOfWork(context);

        ITestEntityReopsitory reopsitory = new TestEntityReopsitory(context);

        ITestEntityservice service = new TestEntityservice(unit_of_work, reopsitory);

        //Consume service here
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. And pardon me i don't understand composition root completely. let say i injected my dependency using constructor. But my question is still the same i guess i am not understanding how would i use same databasecontext  instance between my service and repository.

Comment: After you use constructor injection, you can create your object graph with something like: var context = new DatabaseContext(); var service = new TestEntityService(new CodelookupRepository(context), new UnitOfWork(context)). The idea here is that you create the context once and then you use the same instance many times to construct objects.

Comment: By the way, are you using a DI container?

Comment: Yes I am using unity, can you please take a look of my code now. I have changed it as you suggested.

Comment: You need to use PerResolveLifetimeManager when you register your DatabaseContext (when you map IDatabaseContext to DatabaseContext with Unity Register method). Also make sure that TestEntityReopsitory is injected with IDatabaseContext  instead of DatabaseContext. Also, when you resolve, make sure that the container knows how to resolve the connectionString by using ParameterOverride when you call the Resolve method.

Comment: When you use PerResolveLifetimeManager, only a single instance of the registered type is used in the object graph created by the Resolve method. However, if you call Resolve again you will get a different instance. Make sure that you understand the consequences of this. This is why I think it will be helpful if you specify how you register your types in the container in your question

Comment: var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfwork, UnitOfwork>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());

Comment: please look at the unity configuration above that's how I am adding it. do you have any suggestion on how should I register my services and repository

Comment: You need to use PerResolveLifetimeManager only for IDatabaseContext. You should register ITestEntityReopsitory to map it to TestEntityReopsitory. Since TestEntityservice is just a class, you don't have to register it (as long as you use the TestEntityservice class when you Resolve). Are these only the types you register with the container? I just wanted to make sure that there is not another object in the graph (that you register with Unity) that depends on IDatabaseContext.

Comment: thank you , so I don't need to register unitofwork at all ? and I forgot to mention that I will also have the services interface which will resolve from my viewmodels so I will need to register them as well. is hierarchical lifetime manager is good for  services and repository in that case.

Comment: You do have to register IUnitOfWork. You just don't have to use PerResolveLifetimeManager for it. I.e., container.RegisterType<IUnitOfwork, UnitOfwork>();. Do the same thing for the service interface if you create it. I really don't know about the hierarchical lifetime manager, I have never used it before. You should be OK if you inject your service into your view model, I don't think there is something special here. By the way, when you don't specify a lifetime manager, TransientLifetimeManager is used. This means that a new instance of the class will be created every time it is needed.

Comment: sorry for posting little late but i did some research on PerResolveLifetimeManager()  in unity the problem is that it never get disposed. and that make me curious that it might keep my connection to database alive which seems to be a problem.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue in unity. How many times do you call Resolve on the same instance of UnityContainer? It you do it only once, then using ContainerControlledLifetimeManager has the same effect as using PerResolveLifetimeManager, and you can dispose your context by disposing the container it self. I have seen multiple posts in the internet proposing fixes to this issue. You might want to try them. Your other options are switching to another container. Or (IMO) even better, use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Comment: I edited the answer to show how easy it is to do this using Pure DI.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns like **Unit of work** and **repository** have many ways to implement. F.e. you can implement read-only repositories that returns **active records** that have methods `Update` and `Delete`. Or you can implement repositories that returns **plain old objects** and therefore have methods `Update`, and `Delete`. Finally you can implement read-only repositories that returns **plain old objects**, so methods `Update` and `Delete` should be declared in an **unit of work**.

How to organize an interaction of the repository and the unit of work? This can doing by combining patterns **registry** and **unit of work**:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IUserRepository UserRepository { get; }

    IDataRepository DataRepository { get; }

    void Commit();
}
```

Or you can use unit of work as **service locator**:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    TRepository GetRepository<TRepository>() where TRepository: IRepository;

    void Commit();
}
```

Or you can explicitly specify read-write repositories for unit of work:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Join(IRepository repository);

    void Commit();
}
```

In the last case you can use repositories with units of work as well as without them. In all of these cases you can share the same `DbContext` between repository and unit of work.

Comment: thank you Mark, but I want my unit of work and repository to be independent from each other but still want them to share the dbcontext can you please take a look of my code now I have modified it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to share the unit of work across the repository instances, this will allow you to create code as follows

```
using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = _UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateInstance()) {
   var repository = _RepositoryFactory.CreateRepository<YourType>(unitOfWork);
   var repositoryTwo = _RepositoryFactory.CreateRepository<YourOtherType>(unitOfWork);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

The repository factory

```
BaseRepository IRepositoryFactory.CreateRepository<T>(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
       //Create Instance Here
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response I have modified my code a little bit can you take a look now.

Comment: @bforcode the problem with injecting them into a base class is you force your code to only be able to use one context, which might not always be what you want.  There might be certain circumstance where you would like to make a call to the db on a completely separate context.